# usage of static member as a class typein C++

Tags: c++, static

Based on "c++ primer", the type of a static data member can be the class type of which it is a member:

```
class Bar {
 public:
     // ...
 private:
     static Bar mem1; // ok
 };
```

However, I have a hard time imagining a scenario in which such a feature is useful. I mean, why do you need a variable to be the class type? Can someone give me some examples? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only time that this would really be useful would be in implementing [the "Singleton" pattern](http://kera.name/articles/2010/09/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-8-outsmarting-static-initialization/) (or "Simpleton" to those of us who despise it).

Comment: EDIT:  (or "useful design pattern" to those of us who have more than academic experience).

Comment: I have plenty more than academic experience. There is no need to be rude, Zac, just because somebody doesn't like your favourite design pattern.

Comment: (In particular, since you asked so nicely, trying to enforce only a single object of something makes one wonder whether it should have been an object in the first place. It's an abuse of OO, like so much code out there these days that purports to be object-oriented simply because it uses classes for everything.)

Comment: Its not my favorite design pattern, but it does have its uses; especially in C++ (which is NOT and OO languange).  I wasn't being rude; I was simply stating that outside of academia, there are a ton of places where design patterns (such as Singletons) prevent problems down the road (usually with situations where someone else is tasked with maintaining code you wrote years ago ... where misuse of said code could cause significant problems).  Design your code so that it can only be used in the way you intended - singletons can help you do that in some cases (e.g. object factories/managers).

Comment: Thank you for the link. It clearly explains why use class type instead of pointer to implement singleton pattern.

Comment: @ZacHowland: I know C++ isn't an OO language. And I know singletons *can* be useful; just many of us in the real world prefer to use free functions for equivalent behaviour, *because* C++ isn't an OO language and there is no reason to use objects where they are not appropriate.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Writing an object factory that is tasked with both creating and managing the lifetimes of objects is doable with standalone functions, but you'll find the maintenance of such a system to be a nightmare.  To each their own, but if you tried to write a C-style memory manager on a C++ project, don't be surprised if you get ripped during a code review.

Comment: Using free functions is not "C-style". It's demonstrating that not everything has to be an object. During code review, I rip anyone who made an object where they didn't have to.

Comment: @Tomalak:  In the example I gave, using a set of standalone functions would be C-style.  I agree that you should avoid creating classes that are unneeded (something I loathe about C# and Java), but completely discounting a useful design pattern is rather absurd.  When used properly, it makes future maintainers of your code aware of what you were trying to do and helps prevent them from doing things you did not intend for your code to do.

Comment: @ZacHowland: I never said anything about "completely discounting" it. I said I despise it. :) If I were to completely discount it, I would not have written the rather in-depth article linked to in my answer.

Comment: In which you fail to mention that what you are describing is known as a "Meyers Singleton" and is laid out by Scott Meyers in "More Effective C++" as a solution to some potential singleton pitfalls.

Comment: @ZacHowland: So? I never claimed to have invented it. It's a general pattern that is widely used, for better or worse. My you are hostile today.

Comment: I apologize if I seem hostile.  But when you link an article you "wrote" (which is nothing more than a brief summary to a chapter in a book that was released almost 10 years ago) followed by a fallacious statement about the design pattern ...

Comment: @ZacHowland: I never read that book. My article is an exploration, written in my own words, with my own code, of potential pitfalls with some of the most common approaches to writing singletons. I still can't see what my "fallacious statement" was: I merely stated that I despise singletons, which is absolutely and 100% true.

This comment thread is completely unproductive and unless the topic starts to involve more logic and less rhetoric, I shan't be posting on it again.

Comment: The Meyers and Sutter books should be mandatory reading.  If you haven't done so, I'd suggest picking them up in your free time (there are a few places in them where you'll find that Singletons make for a very clean solution to a problem, while standalone functions would be a massive headache).  The fallacious statement was that the Singleton design pattern is an abuse of OOD.  While it can be implemented in a poor manner (and under the wrong circumstances), some things (e.g. custom memory managers, object factories) lend themselves well to the pattern while alternatives are messy at best.

Answer (score 5):

Singleton is one possible use. Another possible use is to provide one pre-packaged ready-to-use instance.

Suppose your class has expensive constructor, uses tons of memory and you need to create many instances. The good news is most of the instances are identical. You could make the most widely used copy static and reuse it whenever needed.

Example. Bar can be constructed from an integer. An instance constructed from 0 is in high demand. It is a good candidate to be made static.

```
class Bar {
public:
    Bar(int n) : n_bar(n) {
        // if n!=0, construct new instance of Bar, else recycle static instance
    }

    void foo() const { // note, it is const
        if(n_bar==0)
            bar0.foo();
        else {
            // do something
        }
    }
private:
    int n_bar;
    static Bar bar0; // initialize to Bar(0)
};
```

Instead of one static member, you can also create a whole battery of static instances (using std::map with ints as keys and Bars as values) on demand.

Comment: Thank you. This is very interesting. Would you explain a little bit more about how to "else recycle static instance" in the constructor?

Comment: @EXP0. "recycle static instance" means don't do any allocation/computation to build a fresh new instance, because we are going to use bar0 next time foo is called.

Answer (score 4):

[singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

when you have some class that needs to have exactly one instance available globally. using a global variable doesn't restrict to single instance and can have problems with static inialization

Comment: Static data members also have problems with static initialisation. Prefer function-static instances to avoid all static initialisation problems.

Comment: Thank you. After reading your comment, I was going to ask why using class type instead of pointed for singleton, but then I see Tomalak's link. That's why I accepted his answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

one word: [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).